# Como concatenar duas strings em C sem usar biblioteca <string.h>?

Tags: c, array, string, concatenação-de-string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    
    char vet1[20] = "Bom ";
    char vet2[20] = "dia";
    
    for(int i=0; vet1[i]!='\0'; i++){
        for(int j=0; vet2[j]!='\0'; j++){
            vet1[i]=vet2[j];
            printf("%c%c", vet1[i], vet2[j]);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá João. Boas-vindas ao site. Em futuras perguntas é importante adicionar **um [mcve] do problema** com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então tem que descobrir qual é posição onde o primeiro *array* termina, e o primeiro laço até faz isso, mas aí tudo fica confuso, porque é só o que deve fazer nele, não deve ter conteúdo, é só navegar até chegar no final. Então usa uma variável para guardar isso e ela deve sobreviver ao fim do laço inicial.

Depois deve começar copiar o conteúdo do segundo *array* para o primeiro, iniciando na posição que se encontrou antes. Então esse segundo laço para cópia é completamente independente do primeiro, exceto que o início do primeiro *array* vem do resultado obtido no primeiro.

Não considerei ser necessário dar segurança se a cópia estoure o limite do primeiro vetor, em um caso real isso seria necessário.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char vet1[20] = "Bom ";
    char vet2[20] = "dia";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; vet1[i] != '\0'; i++);
    for (int j = 0; vet2[j] != '\0'; j++) vet1[i++] = vet2[j];
    printf("%s", vet1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ph6C6Q). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/zccarggl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Concat2.c).

Dá para fazer com um só laço, mas é ineficiente e confuso.

Comment: vlw até q deu ajudada vou tentar com um laço só

Comment: Agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.